# Provider cannot be found ( ClassNotFoundException ) maven project

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jersey

i have a problem with a maven project with JavaSE-11 .
The dev environment is vscode with a java plugin for manage a project, debug ecc..

I have succefully inserted a module required in module-info.java and the import are all ok
for vscode but when a run the application i have this error at run time:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.2/bin/java -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @/tmp/cp_4bmlvzgw4a4i4xcyfpyjt66n3.argfile -m ale/ale.App 
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/alessio/dev/java/esercizi/jersey-javafx_v0.1/target/classes/ale/login.fxml:11

        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
        at ale/ale.App.loadFXML(App.java:32)
        at ale/ale.App.start(App.java:21)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider for jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cannot be found
        at jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:77)
        at jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:88)
        at ale/ale.LoginController.<init>(LoginController.java:34)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:124)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:346)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:604)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider for jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cannot be found
        at jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:168)
        at jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:62)
        ... 28 more
Exception running application ale.App
```

The ClientBuilder is imported without errors in LoginController.java ( import jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder )

The complete app code is located [here](https://github.com/alegue87/javafx_rest_client)

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: If I'm interpreting the error message correctly, it's not `ClientBuilder` that's missing but a **provider** of `ClientBuilder`. Remember that Java EE (or Jakarta EE, as it's now known) is just a collection of specifications & interfaces. You need to have an implementation on the class-path/module-path.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw for the response. I have tried the same module in a different project with a basic maven archetype and the module ( jersey ) works fine. The problem is in this project with archetype based on javafx. How i can apply your solution?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed similar behavior in my FX client by adding the following dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I hope that solves your issue, cheers.